# How do I connect my summed tables to the date range in a Shiny App?

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, tidyverse, shinydashboard

A simple table output of the count works when I change the dates, but my summed revenue table does not. I have tried using the `group_by` function and `reactive` but no to avail.

```
install.packages(c("shiny","shinydashboard","ggplot2","dplyr","tidyverse","scales","lubridate"))
 #not all of these packages may be necesary. They are just the ones I have been playing with

df <- data.frame("Ship Date" = c(2020-01-05,2020-01-06,2020-01-05,2020-01-06,2020-01-05,2020-01-06
                                 ,2020-01-05,2020-01-06), "Team" = c("Blue","Blue","Green","Green"
                                 ,"Gold","Gold","Purple","Purple"), "Revenue" = c(20,15,17,23
                                 ,18,19,17,12))

ui <- fluidPage(
 dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard",titleWidth = 450),
 dateRangeInput(
  inputId = "daterange",
  label = "Select the date range", start = Sys.Date(), end = Sys.Date(), min = min(df$`Ship Date`),
           max = max(df$`Ship Date`), format = "yyyy/mm/dd", separator = "-" ),
 textOutput("startdate"), textOutput("enddate"), textOutput("range"),
 dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
   column(width = 3, tableOutput('subdatavt')),
   column(width = 3, tableOutput('subdatart'))
)))


server <- function(input, output, session) ({
  output$startdate <- renderText({
    as.character(input$daterange[1])
  })
  output$enddate <- renderText({
    as.character(input$daterange[2])
  })
  output$range <- renderText({
    paste("Selected date range is ", input$daterange[1], "to", input$daterange[2])
  })
#volume by Team
output$subdatavt <- renderTable({
    vt = subset(df, df$`Ship Date`>=input$daterange[1] & df$`Ship Date`<= input$daterange[2])
    table(vt$Team)
  })
#revenue by Team
# here is where I do not know how to go about it. I imagine something to do with the group_by function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

df <- tibble("ShipDate" = as.Date(c("2020-01-05","2020-01-06","2020-01-05","2020-01-06","2020-01-05","2020-01-06","2020-01-05","2020-01-06")), 
             "Team" = c("Blue","Blue","Green","Green","Gold","Gold","Purple","Purple"), 
             "Revenue" = c(20,15,17,23,18,19,17,12))

ui <- fluidPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard",titleWidth = 450),
  dateRangeInput(
    inputId = "daterange",
    label = "Select the date range", start = Sys.Date(), end = Sys.Date(), min = min(df$ShipDate),
    max = max(df$ShipDate), format = "yyyy/mm/dd", separator = "-" ),
  textOutput("startdate"), textOutput("enddate"), textOutput("range"),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 3, tableOutput('subdatavt')),
      column(width = 3, tableOutput('subdatart'))
    )))

server <- function(input, output, session) ({
  output$startdate <- renderText({
    as.character(input$daterange[1])
  })
  output$enddate <- renderText({
    as.character(input$daterange[2])
  })
  output$range <- renderText({
    paste("Selected date range is ", input$daterange[1], "to", input$daterange[2])
  })
  #volume by Team
  output$subdatavt <- renderTable({
    vt = df %>% filter(ShipDate >= input$daterange[1],
                       ShipDate <= input$daterange[2]) %>% 
      group_by(Team) %>% 
      summarise(Revenue = sum(Revenue), n=n()) %>% 
      na.omit
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: What i need is the revenue column added up for each team. That is easy enough to do, but i cannot get it to "attach" to the date filters. The revenue values remain the same no matter how I change the filters. @motch

Comment: I tried using `output$ro <- renderTable({ reactive.tables$Revenue %>% group_by(Team) %>% summarise(Revenue = sum(Revenue), n=n()) %>% na.omit})` That did not work either

Comment: I don't know why that didn't work for you, maybe you forgot to delete table(vt$Team) after. I edited my answer to what I think you wanted

Comment: Thank you @motch. I messed that up. Your code is correct.